# How to make lines in line charts from ng2-charts straight lines?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using ng2-charts to make line charts in my Angular 8 application. But, the line charts are being displayed as curved lines and not straight lines. I'm taking the code from the following link https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/LineChart as you can see, the lines are not straight. How to make them straight lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Pass in `bezierCurve: false` into the options. I.e. `[options]="{bezierCurve: false}"`or `lineTension: 0`. However if you use the new charts you can try: `[datasets]="{data: data, lineTension:0}"`

Comment: @Joel Thank you that worked! Also, I noticed that by default the area under the line graph has a color, I tried "background-color:'none';" but that didn't work and it just put a grey color under it. Is there any way to not have any color under the line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Try: `[options]="{fill: false}"` or `[datasets]="{fill: false}"` or `[options]="{backgroundColor: transparent}`

Comment: [datasets]="{fill:false}" worked, thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass in `bezierCurve: false` into the options like this:

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="{bezierCurve: false}">
</canvas>
```

Or if you use the newer version `lineTension: 0`:

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="{lineTension: 0}">
</canvas>
```

Or if you want to affect a certain dataset:

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
            [datasets]="{data: data, lineTension: 0}"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="lineChartOptions">
</canvas>
```

Unrelated question from OP:

*I noticed that by default the area under the line graph has a color, I tried `background-color:'none';` but that didn't work and it just put a grey color under it. **Is there any way to not have any color under the line?***

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
            [datasets]="{data: data, lineTension: 0, fill: false}"
            [labels]="lineChartLabels"
            [options]="lineChartOptions">
</canvas>
```

`[datasets]="{fill: false}"`

Comment: The solution did not contain the '>' bracket after the canvas tag and will not work in angular component html. I cant seem to edit your solution as it contains less than 6 characters altogether

Answer (score 2):

New version of ng2-chart are in this way:

Javascript Code:

```
 public lineChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0
      }
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <canvas baseChart 
                  [data]="lineChartData"
                  [options]="lineChartOptions">
 </canvas>
```